# Error import for xstatic.pkg.angular_cookies when running manage.py

Tags: python, ubuntu, openstack, manage.py

I try to install AVOS in openstack on my ubuntu server. But when i try to execute

> python manage.py runserver

it turns on that error import for `xstatic.pkg.angular_cookies`. It seems that no one has a similar problem to me. What can I do to fix this?

Here's the application from [CiscoSystems@GitHub](https://github.com/CiscoSystems/avos)